# Getting Azure web-app to display php errors

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to build a quiz type of system with PDO and log in. I was successful when I try the app locally; however whenever I try to log in on Azure with the same code as with my local application, I get error 500.

I was wonder if there was any way to make it display the errors and what I have done wrong.

I've been using webmatrix to deploy the application index.php and such.

Everything is working correct on my local instant so I am curious how can get 
Azure to display some sort of errors and problems. Instead of just error 500.

[image: picture of web-app]

[image: azure error 500]

UPDATE: I added the php.int file to the root or rather same place where the index is. Need a little advise how it is suppose to look like is it just like this

php.int

```
display_errors=On

upload_max_filesize=800m
```

Comment: Hi @Mike, any updates yet?

Comment: Yeah I got it to work thanks a lot :)

Comment: Congratulations! You can mark it as an answer if it is help for you, and which will get them benefit who occur the similar issue with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the PHP_INI_USER, PHP_INI_PERDIR, PHP_INI_ALL configuration settings in Azure Web Apps, please rename the configuration file to **`.user.ini`** in your root directory.

If you want to use the custom configuration file name like `php.ini` in your issue. Please add an **App Setting** to your Web App with the key **PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR** and value `d:\home\site\wwwroot (your root directory path)`.

Restarting the web app forces PHP to read the new settings.

Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime for more.